# Pushing vector elements to a queue

Tags: c++, vector, queue

I have a function which returns a `std::vector`. I want to push each element of the `vector` into a `std::queue`. Is the following expression correct:

`myQueue.push(myVector);`

If it is legal, will it add each element of the vector individually to the queue? Or will it add the entire vector to the queue and then i can use `myQueue.front()` to return the vector and access the elements within the vector?

OR

Do i have to iterate over the vector and push each element to the queue, i.e.

```
for(int i=0, i<myVector.size(); i++)
{
   myQueue.push(myVector[i]);
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: What happens when you try doing it both ways?

Comment: Here are the signatures for the `push` function: `void push( const value_type& value );` and `void push( value_type&& value );`. So what is the `value_type` of your `std::queue` and `std::vector`?

Comment: @JamesAdkison Both are type `MyClass`.

Comment: My point was the `push` function takes the `value_type` of the container (i.e., `MyClass`) therefore the answer should be pretty easy and clear.

Answer (score 2):

You do need to loop over the elements.  (There other ways with inserters, but they all have to loop because these two containers are different types.)  You have it fine, but I'd use new C++ syntax.

```
for (auto &entry: myVector)
    myQueue.push(entry);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate over the vector and push each element to the queue.